# Slicing a PDF document

Tags: c#, pdf

how to slice a pdf document in c#.. here is my code for slicing but while slicing a 10 MB pdf document after slicing total size is 20 MB how to decrease the sliced document while slicing??? please give a good method for slicing and compressing

```
public int ExtractPages(string sourcePdfPath)
    {
        int p = 0;
        try
        {
            iTextSharp.text.Document document;
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(new iTextSharp.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray(sourcePdfPath), new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(""));
            if (!Directory.Exists(sourcePdfPath.ToLower().Replace(".pdf", "")))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(sourcePdfPath.ToLower().Replace(".pdf", ""));
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.Delete(sourcePdfPath.ToLower().Replace(".pdf", ""), true);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(sourcePdfPath.ToLower().Replace(".pdf", ""));
            }

            for (p = 1; p <= reader.NumberOfPages; p++)
            {
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
                    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
                    writer.SetPdfVersion(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_2);
                    writer.CompressionLevel = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStream.BEST_COMPRESSION;
                    writer.SetFullCompression();
                    document.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSize(p));
                    document.NewPage();
                    document.Open();
                    document.AddDocListener(writer);
                    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage pageImport = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, p);
                    int rot = reader.GetPageRotation(p);
                    if (rot == 90 || rot == 270)
                    {
                        cb.AddTemplate(pageImport, 0, -1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(p).Height);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cb.AddTemplate(pageImport, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F, 0, 0);
                    }
                    document.Close();
                    document.Dispose();
                    File.WriteAllBytes(sourcePdfPath.ToLower().Replace(".pdf", "") + "/" + p + ".pdf", memoryStream.ToArray());
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
        return p - 1;
```

Comment: If I read your code correctly, you're splitting up a, say, 50 page PDF into 50 single page PDFs with the same content, right? Why would you expect this to reduce the size? Every PDF file has some overhead besides the content, it just happens that in your case the overhead is as much as the data. (Which might be possible if the content on a single page is simple enough.)

Comment: yes.. after slicing i have to save orginal file and sliced files in server then its taking too much space if i slice a 50 Mb file after slicing it will be 110 MB thats why i have to compress the sliced pdf documemnts

Comment: Can you throw them into a `.zip` archive? This might get rid of the redundant overhead. Also if space is a priority for you why split up the files at all? Just extract the single pages on demand. (Is space a priority? A 200% blow-up looks scary, but storage is pretty cheap.)

Comment: because of performance, issue that's why i am splitting the pdf document, but while printing time i will get only one page in a object, instead of that i have to print the entire document but i cant load entire document in a same object, for that iam introducing new iframe then printing, i can chose two method, after slicing i can compress, next one while slicing i can compress, which one is good method?? i have to compress the sliced pdf pages into small size

Comment: I'm just saying, it's a completely unreasonable expectation to want the total size of the separate PDF pages to not be bigger than the original document. Is the performance of extracting a single page out of a PDF that slow? You don't need to always do this on-demand - you can cache the single-page PDFs as temporary files and clean out old ones to save space.

Answer (score 0):

PDF operates with a notion of resources.  Any large memory-consuming objects within the document are typically considered to be resources that can be shared across the document.  The types of shareable resources are fonts, images, page templates (forms - not AcroForms), color spaces, graphics state objects, patterns, and proc sets.  If I use the font Basketball Overextended on pages 1, 2, 3, and 4, there need only be 1 copy of Basketball Overextended embedded in the file.

When you separate the document into 4 different pages, iText will do exactly what you ask it to do: embed the font in each of the files.

Since fonts are typically large, this is the most likely reason your files appear to be bloating.

If you want your documents to render correctly anywhere, this is the correct thing to do.

That's not to say that there aren't options.  For example, if iText is clever enough, it may be able to generate a font subset for each page - in other words, analyze your font usage and only embed the parts of the font that are actually used.

You might also be able to remove the font embedding entirely.  As long as you leave the metrics and the font descriptor behind, Acrobat will try pretty hard to generate an equivalent font for you and even use the right one if it's available on the target system, but if the document uses esoteric fonts, good luck with that - your end users will see a document that looks just plain wrong.